# Is it possible to create a table in current database of wordpress using a static page only (not creating as plugin)?

Tags: wordpress

I wrote my code as bellow,

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name:Register Page
    Template URI:
    Author:yuva
    Author URI:
    Description:This Is Page for Gallery.
    */

    get_header();
    ?>
    <div class="regist">
    <h2><?php  the_title(); ?></h2>

    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $my_table=$wpdb->prefix.'your_users';

    $sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $my_table (id int(20) not null auto_increment,name varchar(40) not null,password varchar(20) notnull,PRIMARY KEY(id))";

    include_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');

    dbDelta($sql);

    ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    get_footer();
    ?>
```

Can any one help me solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes,it is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Since this code has nothing to interact with the user how about writing the above code in your function.php instead of the template page??

And yes you can surely create tables if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but don't forget to use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` .Otherwise your query create new table every time when page is executed and your previous data will be lost.